# Struggling to filter data in R

Tags: r

Here is the data that I am using :

https://www.dropbox.com/s/dl/chmzqmus6bfoaim/climate_clean.csv

I added a variable called `average_temperature_fahrenheit` by doing so

`climate = mutate(climate, average_temperature_fahrenheit = 9/5*average_temperature_celsius+32)`

Now I want to know the highest temperature in Fahrenheit during the months of June, July and August between 1970 and 1980 in Europe and North America so I thought I needed to filter my data frame `climate` by doing so

`climate %>%  filter(continent == c("Europe","North America") & month == c("Jun","Jul","Aug")  & year[1970:1980])`

But clearly I did not succeed because it shows me only the month of August

Please could you tell me where I messed up in the `filter` function part

Comment: `climate %>% filter(continent %in% c("Europe","North America"), month %in% c("Jun","Jul","Aug"), year >= 1970, year <= 1980)`

Answer (score 0):

You could go with

```
library(data.table)

climate <-fread("~/downloads/climate_clean.csv")

climate %>%
  mutate(average_temperature_fahrenheit = 9/5*average_temperature_celsius+32) %>%
  filter(year %in% 1970:1980, month %in% c("Jun", "Jul", "Aug")) %>%
  group_by(continent) %>%
  summarise(MaxF = max(average_temperature_fahrenheit))


# A tibble: 6 x 2
  continent      MaxF
  <chr>         <dbl>
1 Africa         93.6
2 Asia           98.6
3 Europe         83.9
4 North America  83.0
5 Oceania        83.7
6 South America  80.2
```

Answer (score 0):

You could `rev`erse the `rank` function touse it in `ave` and subset the data where it's `1`. Instead of creating a long spaghetti of code I'd do subsetting in multiple steps.

```
## subset by month, year, continent
res <- climate[climate$month %in% month.abb[6:8] & climate$year %in% 1970:1980 &
                 climate$continent %in% c("Europe", "North America"), ]
## create rank
res <- transform(res, 
                 ave.temp.F=average_temperature_celsius * 9/5 + 32,
                 rank=ave(average_temperature_celsius, iso3,
                               FUN=function(x) rev(rank(x))))
## subset by rank
res <- res[res$rank == 1, ]
## some ordering (`-9` drops the rank column)
res <- res[order(res$continent, res$year, res$month, res$iso3), -9]
```

### Result

```
res
#                               country iso3     continent year month average_temperature_celsius average_rainfall_mm ave.temp.F
# 177956                          Italy  ITA        Europe 1970   Aug                    20.41250            77.53980   68.74250
# 189836                         Monaco  MCO        Europe 1970   Aug                    17.54660            51.22330   63.58388
# 179535                     Kazakhstan  KAZ        Europe 1971   Aug                    19.82530            18.28780   67.68554
# 148959                        Armenia  ARM        Europe 1972   Aug                    19.71050            34.85870   67.47890
# 150399                     Azerbaijan  AZE        Europe 1972   Aug                    23.73650            18.82320   74.72570
# 206420                          Spain  ESP        Europe 1972   Aug                    20.46590            29.92810   68.83862
# 170559                        Georgia  GEO        Europe 1972   Aug                    19.18560            66.58620   66.53408
# 198500                       Portugal  PRT        Europe 1972   Aug                    20.93670             6.03864   69.68606
# 200799                         Russia  RUS        Europe 1972   Aug                    11.89720            61.69850   53.41496
# 146684                        Albania  ALB        Europe 1974   Aug                    21.45010            46.19520   70.61018
# 152444                        Belarus  BLR        Europe 1974   Aug                    17.00830            43.09090   62.61494
# 163047                         Cyprus  CYP        Europe 1974   Aug                    27.13730             3.16681   80.84714
# 167204                        Estonia  EST        Europe 1974   Aug                    15.27410            56.88330   59.49338
# 169004                        Finland  FIN        Europe 1974   Aug                    13.47990            91.12890   56.26382
# 171884                         Greece  GRC        Europe 1974   Aug                    23.14990            13.01370   73.66982
# 184844                      Lithuania  LTU        Europe 1974   Aug                    16.37240            53.21470   61.47032
# 182684                         Latvia  LVA        Europe 1974   Aug                    15.71120            59.34710   60.28016
# 185564                      Macedonia  MKD        Europe 1974   Aug                    20.34650            33.97170   68.62370
# 215084                        Ukraine  UKR        Europe 1974   Aug                    19.58960            39.45000   67.26128
# 156042                       Bulgaria  BGR        Europe 1974   Jun                    17.94660            66.96620   64.30388
# 154602         Bosnia and Herzegovina  BIH        Europe 1974   Jun                    15.80810           128.16000   60.45458
# 189522                        Moldova  MDA        Europe 1974   Jun                    18.23260            87.43030   64.81868
# 199602         Republic of Montenegro  MNE        Europe 1974   Jun                    14.96460           103.38300   58.93628
# 175496                        Iceland  ISL        Europe 1975   Aug                     8.40970            87.26150   47.13746
# 187736                          Malta  MLT        Europe 1975   Aug                    25.47840            36.46360   77.86112
# 194936                         Norway  NOR        Europe 1975   Aug                    11.25500            74.38320   52.25900
# 209336                         Sweden  SWE        Europe 1975   Aug                    13.22820            60.74740   55.81076
# 149948                        Austria  AUT        Europe 1976   Aug                    12.60120            98.79700   54.68216
# 163628                 Czech Republic  CZE        Europe 1976   Aug                    15.39740            55.42650   59.71532
# 162188                        Croatia  HRV        Europe 1976   Aug                    16.69060            98.21130   62.04308
# 175148                        Hungary  HUN        Europe 1976   Aug                    17.16470            48.66250   62.89646
# 198188                         Poland  POL        Europe 1976   Aug                    15.82960            48.73520   60.49328
# 200348                        Romania  ROU        Europe 1976   Aug                    16.03970            85.58330   60.87146
# 199988             Republic of Serbia  SRB        Europe 1976   Aug                    16.82680            78.80250   62.28824
# 204308                       Slovakia  SVK        Europe 1976   Aug                    14.86390            53.49560   58.75502
# 204668                       Slovenia  SVN        Europe 1976   Aug                    14.87980            98.93020   58.78364
# 213519                         Turkey  TUR        Europe 1977   Aug                    22.37990             7.52567   72.28382
# 147452                        Andorra  AND        Europe 1978   Aug                    18.81170            33.16530   65.86106
# 152852                        Belgium  BEL        Europe 1978   Aug                    15.65460            39.78100   60.17828
# 169412                         France  FRA        Europe 1978   Aug                    17.11220            41.63730   62.80196
# 215852                 United Kingdom  GBR        Europe 1978   Aug                    13.77240            83.64290   56.79032
# 177332                        Ireland  IRL        Europe 1978   Aug                    13.97130            86.99350   57.14834
# 185252                     Luxembourg  LUX        Europe 1978   Aug                    15.21680            43.07880   59.39024
# 192452                    Netherlands  NLD        Europe 1978   Aug                    15.46520            48.70340   59.83736
# 209744                    Switzerland  CHE        Europe 1979   Aug                    12.49180           191.84800   54.48524
# 171224                        Germany  DEU        Europe 1979   Aug                    15.89550            71.42340   60.61190
# 164024                        Denmark  DNK        Europe 1979   Aug                    15.08630            80.27490   59.15534
# 167984                  Faroe Islands  FRO        Europe 1979   Aug                     9.45723            82.92610   49.02301
# 184544                  Liechtenstein  LIE        Europe 1979   Aug                     9.05277           217.23500   48.29499
# 172208                      Greenland  GRL North America 1971   Aug                    -6.22770            52.95410   20.79014
# 157820                         Canada  CAN North America 1972   Aug                     9.42089            53.17810   48.95760
# 148124            Antigua and Barbuda  ATG North America 1974   Aug                    26.48220           174.62500   79.66796
# 151004                        Bahamas  BHS North America 1974   Aug                    27.64530           149.01000   81.76154
# 162524                           Cuba  CUB North America 1974   Aug                    27.07380           110.54600   80.73284
# 164684                       Dominica  DMA North America 1974   Aug                    25.12810           145.65000   77.23058
# 165044             Dominican Republic  DOM North America 1974   Aug                    25.07960           143.50400   77.14328
# 174404                          Haiti  HTI North America 1974   Aug                    25.46790           152.89300   77.84222
# 178364                        Jamaica  JAM North America 1974   Aug                    25.69750           329.85900   78.25550
# 207164            St. Kitts and Nevis  KNA North America 1974   Aug                    25.65000           181.47400   78.17000
# 198884                    Puerto Rico  PRI North America 1974   Aug                    26.26840           246.12400   79.28312
# 212564            Trinidad and Tobago  TTO North America 1974   Aug                    26.11950           182.57200   79.01510
# 216176                  United States  USA North America 1975   Aug                    18.68970            64.20100   65.64146
# 196375                         Panama  PAN North America 1975   Jul                    24.11360           325.95700   75.40448
# 161454                     Costa Rica  CRI North America 1975   Jun                    23.90800           333.15800   75.03440
# 153223                         Belize  BLZ North America 1979   Jul                    26.74570           349.16200   80.14226
# 172662                        Grenada  GRD North America 1979   Jun                    27.77390           239.63500   81.99302
# 173022                      Guatemala  GTM North America 1979   Jun                    24.49050           400.83000   76.08290
# 174822                       Honduras  HND North America 1979   Jun                    24.59780           372.34600   76.27604
# 207582                      St. Lucia  LCA North America 1979   Jun                    26.97770           335.70000   80.55986
# 189222                         Mexico  MEX North America 1979   Jun                    24.40470            81.00740   75.92846
# 193542                      Nicaragua  NIC North America 1979   Jun                    25.30880           466.90400   77.55584
# 166182                    El Salvador  SLV North America 1979   Jun                    24.14100           348.93900   75.45380
# 207942 St. Vincent and the Grenadines  VCT North America 1979   Jun                    28.16000           252.66000   82.68800
```